# $watch in class syntax not working

Tags: angularjs

The watch is only working for the first time, when page is loading using the following code:

```
import angular from 'angular';

import '../style/app.css';

class AppCtrl {

  constructor($scope) {
    this.url = 'https://github.com/preboot/angular-webpack';
    this.val = 0;
    this.even = true;
    this.scope = $scope;    
    this.scope.$watch('val', this.valChanged());

  }

  inc() {
    this.val++;
    this.even = this.val % 2 == 0 ? true : false;     
  }

  valChanged(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log('changed');
  }
}

AppCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

const MODULE_NAME = 'app';

angular.module(MODULE_NAME, [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

export default MODULE_NAME;
```

Whenever I click on button which calls the inc() method, value is updated but valChanged method is not fired.

using angularjs v 1.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.scope.$watch(() => this.val, 
                 (newVal, oldVal) => this.valChanged(newVal, oldVal));
```

Comment: Read the doc. The first argument is supposed to be a function returning the value to watch, or a scope expression. 'val' is a scope expression, but val is not an attribute of the scope, it's a propert of the controller. The second argument is supposed to be a function to call when the value changes. But you're calling this.valChanged() and passing what it returns (i.e. undefined).